# Rails - how to delimit a reserved sql keyword

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a sort routine that worked in other apps/sections. However, it appears that the resulting query doesn't work because the associated table is named `user` which apparently is a reserved SQL word. The fix is to have the query reference '[user].name' instead of `user.name`

The line that is causing the problem is

```
   @workflows = @workflows.includes(:user).order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction])
```

The error I get is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Workflows#index
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development/app/views/workflows/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:

TinyTds::Error: Cannot call methods on nvarchar.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [pd].[workflows].[id] AS t0_r0, [pd].[workflows].[title] AS t0_r1, [pd].[workflows].[user_id] AS t0_r2, [pd].[workflows].[created_at] AS t0_r3, [pd].[workflows].[updated_at] AS t0_r4, [pd].[users].[id] AS t1_r0, [pd].[users].[login] AS t1_r1, [pd].[users].[group_strings] AS t1_r2, [pd].[users].[name] AS t1_r3, [pd].[users].[ou_strings] AS t1_r4, [pd].[users].[email] AS t1_r5, [pd].[users].[created_at] AS t1_r6, [pd].[users].[updated_at] AS t1_r7 FROM [pd].[workflows] LEFT OUTER JOIN [pd].[users] ON [pd].[users].[id] = [pd].[workflows].[user_id]  ORDER BY user.name asc'
Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/workflows/index.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_workflows_index_html_erb__557116297_91831440'
Request
```

The url looks like `http://localhost:3000/workflows?direction=asc&sort=user.name`

Can I modify the @workflows =  line so that it will put user in []'s ?

Comment: Any special reason why the table is not named `users`?

Comment: @chris-mendla Your `order` clause is vulnerable for the SQL injections (details [here](http://rails-sqli.org/#order)). So, to solve your problem and SQL injection need to map values of `sort` and `direction` params to safe SQL expressions for ORDER BY statement use any appropriate way (if/case statement, hash, meta-programming, etc).